# Why is Rails before_update callback deprecated? What's the alternative?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, ruby-on-rails-6, beforeupdate

I looked at https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/before_update and it says before_update got deprecated. Does anybody know why that is and what would be the alternative?

I have some code logic that needs to run specifically when an existing record is updated. Before_save is called on both create and update, so I can't use that.

Edit: I guess I can do before_save :do_stuff, if: !self.new_record? but I find this still odd..

Edit2: !self.new_record? inside the if: block doesn't work. I need to put the !self.new_record? logic inside the actual method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `before_update` has been deprecated in Rails 6. I would advise on using api.rubyonrails.org ([in this case](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)) as the preferred reference as it more closely follows the API. You can also have a look at the [source directly and see that it's still there](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb#L301). Lastly, the latest version of the Rails Guides suggests [it is still an available callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#updating-an-object). Try using `before_update` in your Rails 6 application, and see if it works as expected.